# Can "wait" be used as an intransitive verb? Why?

Tags: verbs, intransitive-verbs

"The man was waiting at the side of the road."
Book says that "was waiting" is an intransitive verb but why?

Comment: because there is no object (either direct or indirect)

Comment: İs it mean that, we shouldn't decide without looking the sentence? If there is a object, it is transitive. It's not matter that the verb can be used with object?

Comment: Google for an explanation about transitive and intransitive verbs and you'll recognize them in sentences.

Comment: Okay, I found. Many verbs can be either transitive or intransitiv, and "wait" can be transitive or intransitive. :)

Comment: In examples like "wait for someone", "wait at table" and "wait on someone", the verb "wait" is being used intransitively. But in "You must wait your turn" it is transitive.

Comment: @Centaurus If you wait _for_ someone, or _on_ someone, or _at_ a table, or _by_ the side of the road, you don't have an object—you have a prepositional phrase complement. In fact, in normal parlance _wait_ is rarely transitive (unless you count bare temporal expressions as objects, which some do and some don't).

Comment: The verb *wait* is nearly always intransitive.  Exceptions are scenarios like "Wait your chance" or "Wait your turn". Whenever you wait something, it's transitive.  Otherwise it isn't.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  My mistake.  I just confused French and English grammar.  In French, a verb can be transitive direct (Raoul entend le téléphone), transitive indirect  (Jean-Louis parle à Isabelle) and intransitive (Elle est arrivée hier)  In English verbs are either transitive (transitive direct in French grammar) or intransitive (transitive indirect and intransitive in French grammar).  That's how I confused all that.

Comment: @Centaurus “Transitive indirect” corresponds to having an indirect object, essentially. In French, pronominal indirect objects are marked by case alone (“Il _lui_ a raconté l’histoire”), but non-pronominal ones require a preposition. In English, both can either take a preposition or depend on case/position alone (“He told _her/the woman_ the story” ~ “He told the story _to her/the woman_”). So in English, you can just call them ditransitive or see them as having a prepositional complement; but in French, you need to think of a term that covers both, hence ‘indirect transitive’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Yes, I can see that now.  Thanks for pointing out my mistake.  :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The verb is transitive if it can take an object without a preposition. For example, "to take" is transitive, because you can say "take a bus", "take me there", "take it", "take my pen", etc., and that will be correct.

As for "to wait", it is an transitive verb, you cannot say "*wait a bus", "*wait me there", etc., because those phrases are wrong. You either use this verb alone, without an object, "wait!", or you have a prepositional object after it, usually with the preposition "for": "wait for me!", "I'm waiting for a friend", etc.

Comment: It can be used transitively in "You should wait your turn".

Comment: As Bill points out in his comment to the question, you can “wait your turn”, which is a transitive usage. You can also “wait half an hour”, which some would consider a transitive usage.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Both your and BillJ's examples have temporary expressions that can hardly be considered objects. Although they have nouns in them, if to think like you suggest, "come" can also be transitive, because you can say "come home".

Comment: Certainly *waiting tables* is a transitive use.

Comment: Turns and chances are just as much grammatical objects here as are tables.

Comment: @tchrist - If you mean the action that waiters do, that's a different verb, a homonym.

Comment: @YellowSky ‘Your turn’ is not a temporal expression. Some do consider bare temporals objects, though of course many do not; which is why I caveated that example.

Comment: @BillJ I agree with Yellow Sky. "You should wait your turn" is short for "You should wait until your turn comes". I would call it just **colloquial** usage of an intransitive verb as in ":Please don't wait dinner for us". Also, it is different usage from "to wait tables". It is just an idiomatic and colloquial usage, too.

Comment: @Rathony. No one would normally say "You should wait until your turn comes" - far too stuffy[link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wait+your+turn%2C+wait+until+your+turn+comes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwait%20your%20turn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwait%20until%20your%20turn%20comes%3B%2Cc0) Colloquial or not, "your turn" is still an NP as object of "wait". "You should wait until your turn comes" is best regarded as the semantic interpretation, not the syntactic one. 5th ex here [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wait)

Comment: @BillJ Well, It's not that I am not aware of that. Sometimes, it feels funny when I discuss transitiveness and intransitiveness of English verbs. The same feeling when I discuss part of speech.

Comment: @Rathony “Please don't wait dinner for us” isn't a colloquial usage—it's old-fashioned, if anything. It is unequivocally transitive, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the comment. As you know, I am not capable of telling clearly whether one expression is archaic or colloquial, but I know it has been used. My point is, let;s say you should use "sleep with someone" to express "to have intercourse with someone", but if someone starts to use "sleep her" and it gets traction in the future, it might be used by people. Then, is to sleep transitive or intransitive? I don't see this argument very meaningful because almost all English verbs can function as both. What's the point of arguing whether one verb is transitive or intransitive?